# IntelliJ is acting cray cray with imports

Tags: intellij-idea

After moving files in and out because I wasn't sure of the structure IntelliJ is just going absolutly mental on me:

My class is situated in  main.java.entities.FailedAttempt

**Scenario 1**

```
import main.entities.FailedAttempt;
```

Here it says entities is not found (which is correct) yet it **finds the class**

**Scenario 2**

```
import main.java.entities.FailedAttempt;
```

Here it finds the import of entities (it should not) but **doesn't find the class!**

**Scenario 3**

```
import main.java.entities.*; 
...
private List<FailedAttempt> faList = new ArrayList<FailedAttempt>();
```

Here the import is correct - no error message - but it's unused and private `List<FailedAttempt>` cannot be resolved.

---

**What I did:**

The package was originally named main.java which contained a bunch of other packages. I renamed it to main, then created another java package in it and put all the other class in that java package. Resulting in exactly what I had at the beggining.. Except for the imports which are totally messed up.

Can I somehow resolve this ? I've a feeling I'll have to manually change the class names, invalidate cache, delete project and reimport the folder into intelliJ. But if there is a better method I'm all for it.

I created an issue on their tracker

Answer (score 1):

Use this icon:

[image]

to open the project structure and set it up structure using Project Settings -> Modules under Sources:

[image]

Last, you should check, that everything is exported. You can do that under Artifacts.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had to close the project, Import a new project from an earlier git version and work from there. If someone has this in the future and doesn't use cvs I think it's gonna be annoying.